# Load only visible rows of ArrayAdapter on Android

Tags: android, ios, uitableview, listview, android-arrayadapter

in my Android application I've to make a Calendar, and for each day i have to show the events of the day (they are pngs).
For this, for each row of my ListView, I search in the Database for the events at the row date.

On iOS works fine, because the UITableView loads only visible rows, so the application didn't make the user wait. There's a similar thing on Android?

How I can load only visible rows of an ListView (I use an ArrayAdapter for provide information for the ListView)?

Comment: You mention a database call.  Are you getting the events from a local SQLite DB or from a service call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a DB local to the device (e.g. a SQLite database), you can use a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) for this.

[Vogella has a good tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) on how to implement a ContentProvider and use a CursorLoader with a SQLite database.

Comment: ok, but if I run these in a secondary thread, the users when see the calendar he doesn't see the events for a few of seconds...because the thread is not finished yet!

Comment: Try implementing an Adapter Holder Pattern in your adapter.

Comment: It is a static class that holds the view elements of a list row for reuse in the listview.  Using it will speed up the rendering of each row.  Google for examples.